# Microsoft Graph POST New Row to Excel Table

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to post a new row of data to an Excel table. I am sending a POST request to the Table / Rows. A new row is being added but with empty values. This happens both when I POST from code and also if I POST from the Microsoft Graph Explorer.

The POST statement I am using is:

```http
POST /v1.0/drives/{driveid}/items/{itemid}/workbook/tables/{tableid}/rows
content-type: Application/Json
authorization: Bearer {access-token}
{
    "value": [{
        "values": [
            ["44444 : 22/08/2017 12:14:46",
                "44444",
                "22/08/2017 12:14:46",
                "New Name",
                "Status",
                "01/10/2017 12:14:46",
                "563",
                "Filename"
            ]
        ],
        "index": null
    }]
}
```

I get a successful response message but with empty field values and the table has a blank row added.

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives({driveid)/items(itemid)/workbook/tables({tableid})/rows/$entity",
    "@odata.id": "/drives({driveid})/items({itemid})/workbook/tables({tableid})/rows(null)",
    "index": 2,
    "values": [
        [
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        ]
    ]
}
```

How do I get the POST to include the values into the new row?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON needs to be formatted like this as well as needing to have a value for each column in the table.

`{ "values": [ [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29" ] ] }`

Answer (score 0):

After more experimenting I have found what I have done wrong.  My table has more columns in it than I was posting to.  You need to post to all columns.  I needed to add an additional two blank fields in this case.  When the correct number of values was included the post works.